# Redland RDF libraries: why does parsing model from Turtle without base URI cause error?

Tags: c, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf, redland

Why does the following test produce an error? Does [Redland](http://librdf.org/)'s turtle parser insist on a base URI even if all actual URIs are absolute? ([Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) apparently does not.) And how could I find out more about what actually went wrong (i.e. what API call would return an error description, or similar)?

```
librdf_world *world = librdf_new_world();
librdf_world_open(world);

librdf_storage *storage = librdf_new_storage(world, "memory", NULL, NULL);
librdf_model   *model   = librdf_new_model(world, storage, NULL);

librdf_parser* parser = librdf_new_parser(world, NULL, "text/turtle", NULL);

librdf_uri *baseUri = NULL;

const char *turtle = "<http://example.com/SomeSubject> <http://example.com/SomePredicate> <http://example.com/SomeObject> .";

int error = librdf_parser_parse_string_into_model(parser, (const unsigned char *)turtle, baseUri, model);
```

Comment: Jena will use a default base URI, internally chosen (based on the current directory if all else fails), if none is supplied.

Comment: Have you tried adding an error handler with [librdf_parser_set_error()](http://librdf.org/docs/api/redland-parser.html#librdf-parser-set-error) and seeing what the error message says?

Comment: Documentation (where you link to) says: `Deprecated: Does nothing`.

Comment: @AndyS thx, that helps. Do you know if some specification insists on a base URI (even if all actual URIs are absolute such as in the cited example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base URI is required because the [parser says so using `RAPTOR_SYNTAX_NEED_BASE_URI` flag](https://github.com/dajobe/raptor/blob/master/src/turtle_parser.y). It produces the error before even looking at the content in [`raptor_parser_parse_start()`](https://github.com/dajobe/raptor/blob/master/src/raptor_parse.c).

If you know a real base URI is not needed, you can supply a dummy URI such as `.` instead:

```
librdf_uri *baseUri = librdf_new_uri(world, (const unsigned char *)".");
```

To enable better error reports, you should register a logger  with [`librdf_world_set_logger()`](http://librdf.org/docs/api/redland-world.html#librdf-world-set-logger) - the default logger just spits to `stderr`. Return non-0 from the logger function to signal you handler the message yourself. Example:

```
#include <librdf.h>

int customlogger(void *user_data, librdf_log_message *message) {
  fputs("mad custom logger: ", stderr);
  fputs(message->message, stderr);
  fputs("\n", stderr);
  return 1;
}

int main() {

  librdf_world *world = librdf_new_world();
  librdf_world_set_logger(world, /*user_data=*/ 0, customlogger);
  librdf_world_open(world);

  librdf_storage *storage = librdf_new_storage(world, "memory", NULL, NULL);
  librdf_model   *model   = librdf_new_model(world, storage, NULL);

  librdf_parser* parser = librdf_new_parser(world, NULL, "text/turtle", NULL);

  librdf_uri *baseUri = NULL;

  const char *turtle = "<http://example.com/SomeSubject> <http://example.com/SomePredicate> <http://example.com/SomeObject> .";

  int error = librdf_parser_parse_string_into_model(parser, (const unsigned char *)turtle, baseUri, model);

}
```

Running this will result in

```
mad custom logger: Missing base URI for turtle parser
```

(For a real program, add some cleanup etc.)